WSL and Remote Robot - anyone have any luck?
Tinkering around at the moment with WSL v2, Windows 11. WSL running ROS2 - Humble on Ubuntu 22.04
Remote robot is Ubuntu 22.04 and same ROS version.
At the moment ROS2 runs fine in both environments, I am able to ping both machines from one another but I cannot see the Robots's topics in the WSL environment. I suspect there is something blocking around the virtual Bridge and/or Firewall. Just not found it yet. Wondered if anyone else has had success?
Thanks
Mark
